# add hyper-link and font size to echo in PHP

Tags: php

I have PHP code which echoes a header. I want to add a hyperlink (www.google.com for example) to it, and change its font size and font family. How can I do it ?

```
<?php echo $lang['community_header2'];?>
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details to get any help on this.

Comment: can you please be more specific ? this is part of a webpage ( not written by me ),  and if I want to post it here, it will be like 200 pages.

Comment: How do you expect us to know what is behind those 200 pages ? Paste relevant code or give some background about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo '<h1><a href="http://thinkWithYourBrain.com">'. $lang['community_header2'] . '</a></h1>';?>
```

Then use CSS to change font-size and font family.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="community_header"><?php echo $lang['community_header2'];?></a>
```

Then add in your CSS file:

```
.community_header {
    font-family: XXX;
    font-size: 1.Xem;
}
```

(replace Xs with the values you want it to be)

Comment: tnx for your help. I'm going to try it now.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo $lang['community_header2'] . '<a href="domain_name" style="font-size:10px; font-family:somefamily">Link</a>';?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use inline styling... http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: yeah i knwo that, above suggestion was just for practice purpose only, and there are times where you need inline styles aswell, so u can't say that we cant use inline styling.

Comment: True, but the answers posted on SO should suggest best practices, which this isn't